# Django song not being added to 'favourite songs'

Tags: django

I want my users to be able to add certain songs to `Favourite Songs` but although the `success message 'Added to favourite songs'` but when I visit the `Favourite Songs` page, I see no songs there. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

My models.py:

```
class Songs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    lyrics = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    track_image = models.CharField(max_length=2083)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('/', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

My views.py:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'songs': Songs.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)

@login_required
def add_to_fav_songs(request, **kwargs):
    
    fav_song = Songs.objects.filter(id=kwargs.get('id'))
    messages.success(request, f'Added to favourite songs')
    return redirect('/')

class Fav_songs(ListView):
    model = Songs
    template_name = 'fav_songs.html'
    context_object_name = 'fav_song'
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Songs.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

My favoutie_songs.html:

```
{% for song in fav_song %}
  <article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
      
      <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'song-detail' song.id %}">{{ song.title }}</a></h2>
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'author-songs' song.author %}">{{ song.author }}</a>
      </div>
      <br>
      <img class="card-img-bottom" height="339px" width="20px" src="{{ song.track_image }}">
    </div>
  </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How do you store in the db which users added this as favorite songs?

Comment: haven't really thought about it :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Song` is not connected to the `User`, so you never keep track about what user has wat song as favorite.

You should add a `ManyToManyField` to your `Song` model with:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Songs(models.Model):
    # …
    favorited_by = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='favorite_songs'
    )
    # …
```

Then in our view we can add the logged in user to the `favorited_by` field. Since we here *alter* data, this should be done with a POST request:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import loginrequired
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@login_required
@require_POST
def add_to_fav_songs(request, pk):
    fav_song = get_object_or_404(Songs, id=pk)
    fav_song.favorited_by.add(request.user)
    messages.success(request, 'Added to favourite songs')
    return redirect('/')
```

For the `ListView`, we can then filter by the logged in user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class Fav_songs(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Songs
    template_name = 'fav_songs.html'
    context_object_name = 'fav_song'
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Songs.objects.filter(favorited_by=self.request.user)
```

You should change the button to add this to the favorite to a miniform:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'add-to-fav-songs' song.id %}">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Add to Favorite Songs</button>
</form>
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: bro I changed my code and now when I'm clicking the `Add to Favourite Songs` button, it says in the terminal `Method Not Allowed (GET): /add-to-fav-songs/1/` and chrome says `This page isn’t working` . Then when I go to the `Favourite Songs` page, the error `name 'request' is not defined`  in the class based `Fav_songs` view

Comment: @Abrar: you should make a small `<form method="post" action="{% url 'name-of-view' song.id %}"><input type="submit"></form>` to make POST requests to the view.

Comment: it's not changing the erros :(

Comment: @Abrar: please edit the questio and share the template where you wrote items to add these to the favorite ones. You should *not* work with `<a href="...">`, but with a mini-form that makes a POST request.

Comment: it really don't have any template where songs can be added to favourite ones. It's just a button/form a view and a url

Comment: @Abrar: exactly how do you make calls to the `add_to_fav_songs` view?

Comment: By using `<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"> <a href="{% url 'add-to-fav-songs' song.id %}"></a> Add to Favorite Songs</button>` this button

Comment: @Abrar: as said it requires to use a form, and the button to submit the form with a POST request, see the edited answer (the code fragment at the bottom).

Comment: Now it is throwing another error `TypeError at /add-to-fav-songs/1/
add_to_fav_songs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'`

Comment: @Abrar: you likely named the parameter in the path `pk`, but the view uses `id`, so one of the two should be changed.

Comment: Yes now it is working properly, but when I visit the `Favourite-songs` page, the error `name 'request' is not defined` is being thrown at `return Songs.objects.filter(favorited_by=request.user)` this line

Comment: @Abrar: yes, it should be `self.request.user`, not `request.user` in the `ListView`.